# Faxing PDF file using .Net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, fax

I developed a windows service to fax files using VB.NET. It is working for the file formats .bmp,.jpeg. But it is not working for the file type .PDF.

I am using FaxComLib (COM .dll) to send fax. I am getting following error when the service tries to fax .PDF file. "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070483): Operation failed. at FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocumentClass.ConnectedSubmit(FaxServer pFaxServer)

What could be the problem?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Comment: Can you give some more information?  Specifically, how are the documents faxed and what is the failure mode for PDF?

Comment: I am using FaxComLib (COM .dll) to send fax. I am getting following error when the service tries to fax .PDF file.

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070483): Operation failed. at FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocumentClass.ConnectedSubmit(FaxServer pFaxServer)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need to flatten the PDF into a sequence of page images, perhap as TIFF's?

Answer (score 1):

There is some good code here that you can use for figuring out how to convert your pdf to image

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that the server didn't have a Acrobat/Acrobat Reader installed.  Installing Adobe Reader allowed me to use FAXCOMEXLib to send .PDF files without flattening them.

It was as simple as FaxDoc.Body = "foo.pdf".